# How to validate date in BeforePost - TField datatype

Tags: database, validation, delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to validate the user input to ensure that the user has entered a date in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` before it is posted (`BeforePost` event) to the table in the DB and then abort if it is not.

This is for Delphi-7

This is the code I've been using

```
var
dateAudition : TDateTime;
begin
try
DateAudition := tblAudition.Field[4];
except
Abort;
end;
end;
```

I am getting an error `TDateTime and Tfield are incompatible`

Answer (score 1):

If your database field (column) is a `DATE` or `DATETIME`, then you don't need to do anything in `OnBeforePost` - the field won't allow non-date values to be stored.

The error you're getting is because `TDataSet.Fields` is an array of `TField`, and so referencing `tblAudition.Fields[4]` will result in a `TField`, and your code is trying to assign that `TField` to a variable you've declared as `TDateTime`.

If your column is not a `DATE` or `DATETIME`, and you actually do need to validate, you'll need to convert the field value (not the field itself) to the proper type first. Something like this should work:

```
var
  dateAudition: TDateTime;
begin
  try
    dateAudition := StrToDate(tblAudition.Fields[4].AsString);
  except
    Abort;  // This is wrong, BTW. It cancels without telling the user why
  end;
end;
```